# Building SSO using Spring OAuth and Resource servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Agenda: To create an authorization and resource server such that.

1. Rest clients can authenticate and authorize and use tokens to fetch resources about the user.

   > this worked. accessing resources defined at `/rest/user` endpoint is working fine
2. Web clients can SSO using this authorization server

   > I tried using `@EnableOAuth2Sso` and also using `@EnableOAuth2Client`. Both didn't work. 
   >   When using `EnableOAuth2Sso` redirect to oauth server's login happened but redirection back to the app didn't happen.
3. Users can directly log into the authorization server and see if they have an account.

   > this is working but it is skipping authentication and authorization and the page is getting displayed immediately

I have a OAuth server with ResourceConfig and WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userAccountDetailsService")
    UserAccountDetailsService userAccountDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off

        httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()

            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()

        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/userPage/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "HRADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/adminPage/*").hasRole("HRADMIN")

            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout");

        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userAccountDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(2)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/**").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

Isn't it possible to combine and use web resource and oauth resources in the same server?

I'm using 
Spring Boot: `2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and
Spring security-oauth2-autoconfigure: `2.1.3.RELEASE`

The whole source is available in github

Authorization and Resource server:
https://github.com/john77eipe/SpringSecurityDrills/tree/master/securestore-oauth

Spring Web client using EnableOAuth2Client:
https://github.com/john77eipe/SpringSecurityDrills/tree/master/securestore-web-resource-1

Spring Web client using EnableOAuth2Sso:
https://github.com/john77eipe/SpringSecurityDrills/tree/master/securestore-web-resource-2

Comment: You have only restricted `.antMatchers("/rest/user/**").authenticated()`, all other URLS are permitted by default. Add `anyRequest().authenticated()` to your configruation.

Comment: But I do have that specified in the WebSecurityConfiguration right?

Comment: Your `WebSecurityConfiguration` is never called, because `ResourceServerConfig` has a lower order (AFAIK it is 3).

Comment: adding `@Order` on these classes didn't help

Comment: I didn't say that it helps to add `@Order`. I just explained, why your `WebSecurityConfiguration` is behind your `ResourceServerConfig`. Where did you add `@Order`? What number did you set? I already explained that you need to restrict your URL.

Comment: @dur as mentioned by you. I have added it and updated the code above. Still the same issue. Also added the complete source code link.